# OnPostExecute not executed in AsyncTask (C#)

Tags: c#, android, android-asynctask, xamarin

I am making an Android application in Xamarin Studio, but `OnPostExecute()` is not executed.

Within the `DoInBackground()` method, I have this:

```
protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] native_parms) {
    System.IO.Stream ins = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(this.url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.OpenConnection();
        conn.ReadTimeout = 10000;
        conn.ConnectTimeout = 15000;
        conn.RequestMethod = "GET";
        conn.DoInput = true;
        conn.DoOutput = true;

        Dictionary<string, string> queryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        queryParams.Add("username", this.username);
        queryParams.Add("password", this.password);

        System.IO.Stream os = conn.OutputStream;
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        // getQueryString() just builds a query string
        writer.Write(getQueryString(queryParams));

        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
        os.Close();

        // Starts the query
        conn.Connect();
        int response = (int) conn.ResponseCode;
        System.Console.WriteLine(response);
        ins = conn.InputStream;

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = read(ins, conn.ContentLength);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Done the task.");
        return contentAsString;

        // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
        // finished using it.
    }
    finally {
        if (ins != null) {
            ins.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And then this is literally the `OnPostExecute()` method:

```
protected override void OnPostExecute(AsyncTaskResult<bool, Error> result) {
    System.Console.WriteLine("On post execute");
}
```

I'm just calling the `AsyncTask.execute()` method.

And guess what, this is the output:

```
Done the task.
```

How come? And, more importantly, how can I fix it?

Comment: Plenty of people thoroughly enjoy Xamarin Android development. Please refrain from giving opinions like that.

Comment: Is that where the -1 came from?

Comment: Can you show us a bit more code? Hard to say given those few lines.

Comment: Wasn't me, but I agree with @MihaMarkic that more code is needed to be able to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I (still) do not know why it won't work with type parameters. However, in order to make things work, you just need to remove the generics part:

```
public class YourTask : AsyncTask { ... }
```

and then replace all occurrences of publish, progress or result parameters by `Java.Lang.Object`:

```
protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] parms) { ... }

protected override void OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample with generic AsyncTask that works. I don't know what exactly is your problem since you are still not showing all the relevant code. That said, the override OnPostExecute(AsyncTaskResult result) looks wrong to me at first glance - note that my version uses TResult as parmater type (int in my case).

```
public class MyTask: AsyncTask<string, int, int>
    {
        protected MyTask(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
            : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {

        }
        public MyTask()
        {

        }

        protected override int RunInBackground(params string[] @params)
        {
            return 4;
        }

        protected override void OnPostExecute(int result)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("On post execute");
            base.OnPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```